# Why was clear method in custom trigger of global window not been invoked?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have used global window and custom trigger. Then notice that the state size in every checkpoint keeps increasing. So I tried to set breakpoints in clear method and found clear method seems not been invoked. So I guess it is because clear method not been invoked which makes the state size keeps increasing.

main method

```java
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        see.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
        see.enableCheckpointing(5000L, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        see.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(1000L);
        see.setStateBackend(new MemoryStateBackend());
        see.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(3000L);

        DataStream<String> dataStream = generateData(see);
        dataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String,Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String line, Collector<Tuple2<String,Integer>> collector) throws Exception {
                String[] split = line.split(" ");
                for (String s1 : split) {
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(s1,1));
                }
            }
        }).keyBy(0).window(GlobalWindows.create())
              .trigger(PurgingTrigger.of(TimeoutCountTrigger.of(10,1000L))) 
                .process(new CustomProcessWindow())
                .print().setParallelism(1);

        see.execute();
```

Trigger implement:

```java
public class CountWithTimeoutTrigger<T, W extends Window> extends Trigger<T, W> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final long maxCount;
    private final long timeoutMs;

    private final ValueStateDescriptor<Long> countDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("count", LongSerializer.INSTANCE, 0L);
    private final ValueStateDescriptor<Long> deadlineDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("deadline", LongSerializer.INSTANCE, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    private CountWithTimeoutTrigger(long maxCount, long timeoutMs) {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
        this.timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(T element, long timestamp, W window, Trigger.TriggerContext ctx) throws IOException {
        final ValueState<Long> deadline = ctx.getPartitionedState(deadlineDesc);
        final ValueState<Long> count = ctx.getPartitionedState(countDesc);
        final long currentDeadline = deadline.value();
        final long currentTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final long newCount = count.value() + 1;

        if (currentTimeMs >= currentDeadline || newCount >= maxCount) {
            return fire(deadline, count);
        }

        if (currentDeadline == deadlineDesc.getDefaultValue()) {
            final long nextDeadline = currentTimeMs + timeoutMs;
            deadline.update(nextDeadline);
            ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(nextDeadline);
        }

        count.update(newCount); 

        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, W window, Trigger.TriggerContext ctx) {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, W window, Trigger.TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        final ValueState<Long> deadline = ctx.getPartitionedState(deadlineDesc);
        // fire only if the deadline hasn't changed since registering this timer
        if (deadline.value() == time) {
            return fire(deadline, ctx.getPartitionedState(countDesc));
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // ***** this method not been invoked *****
        final ValueState<Long> deadline = ctx.getPartitionedState(deadlineDesc);
        final ValueState<Long> cntState = ctx.getPartitionedState(countDesc);
        final long deadlineValue = deadline.value();
        if (deadlineValue != deadlineDesc.getDefaultValue()) {
            ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(deadlineValue);
        }
        deadline.clear();
        cntState.clear(); 
    }

    private TriggerResult fire(ValueState<Long> deadline, ValueState<Long> count) throws IOException {
        deadline.update(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        count.update(0L);
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }

    public static <T, W extends Window> CountWithTimeoutTrigger<T, W> of(long maxCount, long intervalMs) {
        return new CountWithTimeoutTrigger<>(maxCount, intervalMs);
    }
}
```

I expect the clear method to be called and clear state in clear method, but it seems clear method in trigger not been invoked and state size in every checkpoint keeps increasing.

Comment: Dose the window trigger output , you can see output in your print method ?

Comment: @MIkCode thx, what do you mean the trigger output? The application process fine except for state size keeps increasing. The methods in custom trigger all process fine, but only the overrided clear method haven't been invoked (tried debug and insert some print message in clear).

Comment: i think you need to use  evictors in order to clear all the state that didn't fired and purged.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#evictors

Comment: @MIkCode I have read the doc and tried someway, but didn't find a way how to get the state of trigger. Moreover, as the api doc describe, the clear method is responsible for clearing any state that the trigger might still hold for the given window. Should I call clear method in `fire` before return `TriggerResult.FIRE` as `onProcessingTime` has all the parameter that `clear` needs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Trigger.clear()` method is invoked when the window is closed. This happens when the application time (processing time or event time as defined by `WindowAssigner.isEventTime()`) reaches the end timestamp of the window.

Since a `GlobalWindow` never ends, the end timestamp of a `GlobalWindow` is `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Hence, the `Trigger.clear()` method will never be called if the trigger is applied on a `GlobalWindow`.

Comment: Yes, `PurgingTrigger` will transform custom trigger to a purging trigger which will transform `TriggerResult.FIRE` to `TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE`. With debuging, I found , most of the time , `Trigger.onProcessingTime()` will return `TriggerResult.FIRE` which will then be transformed to `TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE`. But it's sad to say that the `clear` method still not work here.

Comment: You are right. My answer was not correct, sorry. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thx and sorry for late. As you say, do you mean that I should manage the state myself? Such as call `Trigger.clear()` periodically before return `TriggerResult.FIRE` in my custom `CountWithTimeoutTrigger.fire` method.